# Export module in front of function vs at end

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, gatsby

I am developing an app in *GatsbyJS*, and `export`ing one of my *GraphQL* fragments as such:

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

export const w300Image = graphql`
  fragment w300Image on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        presentationWidth
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const squareImage = graphql`
  fragment squareImage on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        presentationWidth
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I `import` and use `squareImage` as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import { squareImage } from '../graphql/imageFragments';
import NonStretchedImage from './nonStretchedImage';

const Image = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      astronaut: file(relativePath: { eq: "gatsby-astronaut.png" }) {
        ...squareImage
      }
    }
  `);
  return <NonStretchedImage fluid={data.astronaut.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="nFront mobile development" />;
};
```

*Note: My IDE warns me that the `squareImage` `import` is never read. However, since that is not true, I am assuming it is just incapable of picking up its presence inside the GraphQL query.*

**Question**

If I change the `export` to the below (i.e. move the `export` to the end of the file), it crashes when compiling with the following error message:

> Error: Invariant Violation: GraphQLCompilerContext: Unknown document
>   `squareImage`.

New export code (only difference is the `export`s having moved to the end):

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const w300Image = graphql`
  fragment w300Image on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        presentationWidth
      }
    }
  }
`;

const squareImage = graphql`
  fragment squareImage on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        presentationWidth
      }
    }
  }
`;

export { squareImage, w300Image };
```

Any idea what's going on here? I thought the two `export`s were identical? Perhaps tree shaking happens in only one scenario?

**EDIT**

Added a `console.log(squareImage)` after the `import`, and the error still appears. In other words, tree shaking is not the culprit.

Comment: For debug purposes, right after your `import { squareImage } from '../graphql/imageFragments';`, put a `console.log(squareImage)`. Does that look like the right thing?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yep, I just did that after posting. No effect. So tree shaking is not the issue.

Comment: Are these real modules, or are you running this through a transpiler before you execute? (e.g. rollup and done vs. babel + webpack or the like)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Running it through GtasbyJS, which uses webpack under the hood. It is during building that it fails.

Comment: In that case I might recommend running through the [mcve] exercise first. Copy your project to a new dir, remove everything except for the main entrypoint and a single module, and see if you can even get it to bundle without graphql or react, since this is a problem related to module loading. Removing the other possibilities is a fairly fast but valuable test (and will allow you to update the post if it's still bad even with vanilla JS modules)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yep, agree, I usually do that. But with Gatsby there is no "minimal" example. It is a full scaffolder like create react app on steriods. It is not possible to pluck it apart per se...

Comment: I was hoping someone with GatsbyJS experience had seen this issue before.

Comment: fair enough, but with only 400 people watching the tag... it might be a while

Comment: you can recreate your gatsby issue with codesandbox.io! it's like codepen, but with node. When you create a new project, look for Gatsby in the list of options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL:DR**: You don't need to import fragment to use it in query with Gatsby

Gatsby [pulls graphql fragments & queries out of your file](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/query-extraction/) and execute them independently. Because of this, exporting / importing graphql fragment works a little differently.

Since all query lives in the same namespace, once you export a named fragment in any of your files, it's available 'globally', i.e you can use it in other queries & fragment without importing them explitcitly.

This is why you can use the fragment GatsbyImageSharpFluid without importing it anywhere in your code.

**Update:** Gatsby only looks for [query inside tagged template in named export](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/5078f03027c868554111f48fbd5d685c403a9fdd/packages/gatsby/src/query/file-parser.js#L263) i.e ``` export const queryName = graphql`` ```, this explains why it breaks when you switch export style.

Comment: Thanks, Derek, helpful. But, the question still remains. Swapping from export in front of function to export at bottom, break the build. Even if you drop the import.

Comment: @Magnus ah, my bad, I've updated the answer & link to the interested line of code where queries are extracted