# Gatsy page query fails to work when using named export at the end of the page. Why?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, es6-modules

I have the following page template in Gatsby.

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

const PageTemplate = props => {
  const { wordpressPage: currentPage } = props.data;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentPage.title }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentPage.content }} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    wordpressPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
      date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
    }
    site {
      id
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default PageTemplate;
```

Which works as expected (taken from tutorial), however I tend to prefer to do all my exporting at the end of the page like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

const PageTemplate = props => {
  const { wordpressPage: currentPage } = props.data;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentPage.title }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: currentPage.content }} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    wordpressPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
      date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
    }
    site {
      id
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default PageTemplate;
export { pageQuery }
```

However this fails to work - `props.data` is `undefined`. It's a subtle difference but why would this cause the pageQuery to not execute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export module in front of function vs at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464780/export-module-in-front-of-function-vs-at-end)

Comment: Gatsby only looks for query inside tagged template in named export i.e `export const queryName = graphql` [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/f859947c5fc1dfe0f99a1ac29ebd30bbbc9b95d1/packages/gatsby/src/query/file-parser.js#L287), which is why it breaks when you switch export style.

Comment: Thanks @DerekNguyen - how do I mark you answer on the other question as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `pageQuery` has to be exported before `PageTemplate` because it is used by it: that's where it gets its `props.data` from, which explains why you are getting `undefined` when exporting it after.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an additional explanation to @hexangel616 who mentioned the order of exports matters:

> I believe pageQuery has to be exported before PageTemplate because it is used by it.

Your exported GraphQL queries have a special role in the [gatsby build process](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/#what-happens-when-you-run-gatsby-build). From the docs:

> At a high level, what happens during the whole bootstrap and build
>   process is:
>
> 1. Node objects are sourced from whatever sources you defined in gatsby-config.js with plugins as well as in your gatsby-node.js file
> 2. A schema is inferred from the Node objects
> 3. Pages are created based off JavaScript components in your site or in installed themes
> 4. **GraphQL queries are extracted and run to provide data for all pages**
> 5. Static files are created and bundled in the public directory

TLDR: In order for gatsby to build properly all your graphql exports have to be in order.

Comment: If this is true then shouldn't this work
`
export { pageQuery };
export default PageTemplate;
`
Which it doesn't.